# Not Working Update input values inside responsive datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

After multiplying two numbers, if Responsive Datatables it does not show
[image]
[image]

My Code :

```
[enter link description here][3]
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dishlame/dmjxac1L/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are writing the calculated value to the DOM (i.e. into the HTML `<td>` cell), inside the `<input>` element.

You can see the value displayed in the browser - but the DataTables object, which manages the HTML table for you, does not know anything about this new value.

Therefore when DataTables re-draws the table (for the "responsive" event), the value disappears.

To work around this, you can change your `calculate()` function:

```js
function calculate(idx){
  var inttemp=ex_normalNum($("#mm_" + idx).val());
  var zarb=separateNum($("#nn_" + idx).val() * inttemp);

  //$("#result_" + idx).val(zarb); // DELETE THIS LINE

  // populate the value in DataTables:
  var resultsCell = $('#example').dataTable().api().cell(idx -1, 2);   
  resultsCell.data(zarb).draw();

  // re-position the cursor after the re-draw:
  $("#mm_" + idx).focus();
}
```

This line:

```
var resultsCell = $('#example').dataTable().api().cell(idx -1, 2);
```

selects the relevant DataTable cell in your table. Note that row and column offsets start at zero - hence `idx -1` means the relevant row, and `2` means the 3rd column.

Then, this line:

```
resultsCell.data(zarb).draw();
```

writes the calculated value into the cell, inside DataTables - and then re-draws the table so that the value is visible.

**Note** - the cell containing the calculated value will no longer be an `<input>` field - it will just be a regular `<td>` cell.  I would recommend this, because you don't actually have the ability to override the calculated value.

Here is my test table:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you verrry much :)))

Now I have a problem with this change, and that is the total sum.
I updated jsfiddle : jsfiddle.net/dishlame/dmjxac1L/14/

Comment: I think you intended to write this as a comment, not an answer - so you should probably delete your answer. I recommend you create a brand new question for this (so more people will see it, not just me!).  But before you do that, you can (a) take a look at [this solution](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/sum()) and see if you can adapt it to your needs; and (b) research existing questions on Stack Overflow - I am sure someone has asked a similar question already - and there are probably some good answers.